# adding together each array within forEach loop javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my code;

```js
var data = [[40, 20, 60], [20, 30, 10], [50, 75, 40]];
var averageData = [];
data.forEach(function(entries) {
    entries.reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a + b[1];
    }, 0);
    console.log(entries);
});
```

I would like to be able to add the numbers from each array together.

But I'm not sure how I can get each array of numbers added together from the `forEach` loop?

From this data I would like to output instead `[120, 60, 165]`.

It is important that the data is within a nested array, the aim is to try get it out of the nested array onto a single line with the above output.

Hope someone can offer some advice!

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [**`Array#map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead

Note that `b[1]` holds nothing(`undefined`) and `entries.reduce` returns a `reduced` value, either return it of keep it in `variable`

```js
var data = [
  [40, 20, 60],
  [20, 30, 10],
  [50, 75, 40]
];
var averageData = data.map(function(entries) {
  return entries.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
});

console.log(averageData)
```

**Edit-**
As suggested in comments by @Tushar, ***ES6 version***

```js
var data = [
  [40, 20, 60],
  [20, 30, 10],
  [50, 75, 40]
];
console.log(data.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)));
```

Comment: **ES6:** `data.map(arr => arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0))`

Answer (score 0):

`reduce()` will return the sum as you want at last. See as below.

```js
var data = [[40, 20, 60], [20, 30, 10], [50, 75, 40]];
var averageData = []
data.forEach(function(entries) {

    var sum = entries.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }, 0)
    console.log(sum)

})
```

Answer (score 0):

If your values are safe (meaning you know where there come from) you could use eval to quickly sum the values.

```
var data = [[40, 20, 60], [20, 30, 10], [50, 75, 40]];
var totals = [];

data.forEach(function(a, i) {
  totals.push(eval(a.join('+')));
});

console.log(totals);
```

Not the most efficient way but it works